# Can a man answer amen with his head uncovered?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Is there a halacha that a man's head must be covered in order to answer amen to someone else's brocha?

Comment: Why would you think there's an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Rav Ovadiah Yosef](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.219.8?lang=bi), one is permitted to answer *Amen* while his head is uncovered:

> מי שמוכרח לישב בגילוי הראש, כגון בבית משפט של גוים, ושמע ברכה מחבירו, מותר לו לענות אמן בגילוי הראש. [ילקוט יוסף, על הלכות השכמת הבוקר, מהדורת תשס''ד, סימן ג']‏
>
> One who is forced to sit with his head uncovered, for example in the courthouses of the *goyim*, and he hears a blessing from another person, he may answer *Amen* with his head uncovered.

However, according to the [*Tzror Hamor*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OXVgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT200&lpg=PT200&dq=%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9&source=bl&ots=Krr3YZQ3nP&sig=D8s4-_bA6AruxS26HMbs4YXUoMI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip5cuphMPTAhUJ9YMKHT1WD6sQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9&f=false) he should not.

Comment: Can you explain the Tzror Hamor? Does he say there that women should not answer amen because their heads are not covered? Perhaps I misunderstood what was written there.

Comment: @Earl As a married woman, her head should have been covered. Therefore, she sinned by saying something holy ("*Amen*") with an uncovered head.

Answer (score 1):

It is prohibited, see Baer Heytev on SA OC Siman 2 sk 6 (the source of the translated statement in in Taz OC 8 sk 3):

> ואסור להזכיר השם בגלוי הראש, ולא מהני אם משים הידים על הראש, שם סימן צ״א סעיף ג. אבל מהרש״ל כתב: אם רוחץ באמבטי ורוצה לשתות, או בלילה שאין לו כובע בראשו, דיו במה שמכסה ראשו בידו. וט״ז סימן ח' וסימן ע״ד פסק דכיסוי היד על הראש מהני לעניין שלא ישב או ילך בגלוי הראש,  **אבל לעניין שיברך או יוציא מפיו דבר קדושה לא מהני כיסוי יד**, ע״ש
>
> ... for blessing or pronouncing holy contents even to cover the head with a hand does not help ...

I remember that someone did read to me a Shut of Rabbi Ovadia that with tefilin without kippa it's good.

Comment: Where does this source even say the word "Amen"? Since when is saying "Amen" a Davar Kedusha?

Comment: @Double AA yes of course, no?

Comment: @kouty even if you will say that this is a problem when one wants to be Yotzeh with someone else's brocha (which is debatable), what about if the person is just answering to my brocha not to be Yotzeh with it?

Comment: @kouty I don't find that obvious.

Comment: @Earl The shevach is dvar shebikdusha, amen is Kel Melech Neeman

Comment: @Double AA you mean that kedusha is to pronounce shem hashem?